# Pandas - Generate New Values from Random Selection of Sample Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataset with 1mil records. I am looking to select a random value from each column to generate a new row to create a sample dataset with 3mil rows. I found a way to do this, however, it takes about 1s per row. Is there a way to make this more efficient and faster?

```
    newRows = 3000000
    newData = pd.DataFrame()
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(newRows):
        dict = {}
        for column in source.columns:
            dict[column] = [source.sample()[column].values[0]]
        newData = newData.append(dict,ignore_index=True)
    end = time.time()
    elasped = end - start
    print(elasped)
    print(newRows/elasped)
```

Comment: How many columns does your DataFrame have?

Comment: @not_speshal 24 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `numpy.random.choice`:

```
import numpy as np

indices = np.random.choice(df.index, size=(newRows, df.shape[1]), replace=True)
newData = pd.DataFrame(data=source.to_numpy()[indices, np.arange(len(source.columns))], 
                       columns=source.columns)
```

Or:

```
newData = source.apply(np.random.choice, size=newRows, replace=True)
```

Comment: `.apply(np.random.choice, size=newRows, replace=True)`.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang - Think the edited (now first) method is better though!

Answer (score 1):

Loops by the columns, sample 3M from each. Then create a new data frame:

```
newRows = 3000000

newData = pd.DataFrame({
   c: source[c].sample(n=newRows, replace=True).values
   for c in source.columns  # `for c in source` works as well
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this works? I'm trying to understand so I can learn from this as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure what to elaborate. The code essentially sample 3M values from each column with `source[c].sample`, then creates the new data from the samples.